# points inside a triangle

Tags: geometry

Let $X,Y,Z$ be the vertices of a triangle, and let $A$ be a point lying within this triangle. For any point $B \neq A$ inside the triangle span by $X,Y,Z$ there exists at least one vertex $U$ of $X,Y,Z$ such that $||B U|| > ||A U||$.

In the above $||C D||$ denotes the Euclidean distance between points $C$ and $D$).

It looks correct to me, but I couldn't find a simple proof.

Comment: Don't you mean... a triangle ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Or perhaps $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are three vertices of a polygon (a proper subset).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: but what is "the polygon span by $X,Y,Z$", then ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust That would be the convex hull, I guess (which is a triangle).  However, it seems that this question doesn't depend on the polygon; it looks like the statement that if you have a triangle with vertices $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ and two points $A$ and $B$ in the triangle, there is some vertex closer to $A$ than $B$.

Comment: Yes, he was right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locus of the points closer to $A$ than to $B$ is the half plane delimited by the bisector of $AB$. By convexity of the triangle, none of the two half-planes is void of a vertex, otherwise this whole half-plane would be void.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of pairs of vertices of the triangle.